# what kind of Control used to switch between pages

Tags: c#

In the form pictured below, the entire content of the right side changes when an item is selected on the left side. Which control can I use to accomplish this effect? I’ve tried a ListBox if anyone can put the code or the design tools .

Picture of form:

[image]

Comment: C is not C++ is not C#. Please use only the relevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

The left side is most likely a Win32 [TreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) control.  The pane on the right is almost certainly a [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

There's really nothing that will automatically swap the views out when you click on the tree control.  You'll have to write you own code to toggle the main pane's view based on the item selected in the tree.

Comment: dear Selbie i know not automatically swap but i need a code that change the entire form in the right or the event to use                                         e.g. i have listbox in the left side what is the code must be write to swap the content of form in the right and what should i use a panel or groupbox in the right please advise